# How do I query posts by a sub value with the API?

Tags: ajax, javascript, json, rest-api

This is my first time working with REST, and I'm having difficulty getting posts by a meta key. I've added the meta keys I need using `register_meta`, and running a request on `/wp-json/wp/v2/products`, the output does contain my custom fields.

I know I can add `?slug={some slug}`, or `?id={some id}` to retrieve posts by those values, and that works fine in testing. But I can't figure out how to parse the custom fields because they're nested in the JSON data under a "meta" listing.

After Googling around for about an hour to no avail, I just started guessing at what I was supposed to do. I've tried a number of things like `?brand_name=test`, `?meta[brand_name]=test`, and `?[meta]brand_name=test`, but none of those seem to do anything.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious; I'd really appreciate some help. An example of my JSON data is below.

```
[
   {  
      "id":5,
      "date":"2017-05-04T10:36:10",
      "date_gmt":"2017-05-04T15:36:10",
      "guid":{  
         "rendered":"http:\/\/products.example.localhost\/?post_type=product&#038;p=5"
      },
      "modified":"2017-05-09T13:41:12",
      "modified_gmt":"2017-05-09T18:41:12",
      "slug":"12545xa573",
      "status":"publish",
      "type":"product",
      "link":"http:\/\/products.example.localhost\/products\/12545xa573\/",
      "title":{  
         "rendered":"12545XA573"
      },
      "excerpt":{  
         "rendered":"",
         "protected":false
      },
      "author":1,
      "featured_media":32,
      "comment_status":"open",
      "ping_status":"open",
      "template":"",
      "format":"standard",
      "meta":{  
         "brand_name":"test",
         "sku":"12545XA573",
         "unit_of_measure":"FT, 1\/8, 1\/16",
         "length":"3.20 in"
      },
      "_links":{  
         "self":[  
            {  
               "href":"http:\/\/products.example.localhost\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/products\/5"
            }
         ],
         "collection":[  
            {  
               "href":"http:\/\/products.example.localhost\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/products"
            }
         ],
         "about":[  
            {  
               "href":"http:\/\/products.example.localhost\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/types\/product"
            }
         ],
         "author":[  
            {  
               "embeddable":true,
               "href":"http:\/\/products.example.localhost\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/users\/1"
            }
         ],
         "replies":[  
            {  
               "embeddable":true,
               "href":"http:\/\/products.example.localhost\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/comments?post=5"
            }
         ],
         "version-history":[  
            {  
               "href":"http:\/\/products.example.localhost\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/products\/5\/revisions"
            }
         ],
         "wp:featuredmedia":[  
            {  
               "embeddable":true,
               "href":"http:\/\/products.example.localhost\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/media\/32"
            }
         ],
         "wp:attachment":[  
            {  
               "href":"http:\/\/products.example.localhost\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/media?parent=5"
            }
         ],
         "curies":[  
            {  
               "name":"wp",
               "href":"https:\/\/api.w.org\/{rel}",
               "templated":true
            }
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

Comment: Get posts by meta field is no longer available by default. Some suggestions here: https://1fix.io/blog/2015/07/20/query-vars-wp-api/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access posts via meta key you need to hook into the [`rest_query_vary` filter].[1](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_query_var-key/) 
The example I was thinking of when I read your question is [the same one found on the post](https://1fix.io/blog/2015/07/20/query-vars-wp-api/) [@WebElaine](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/102815/webelaine) commented. I've merely added it below:

```
function my_allow_meta_query( $valid_vars ) {

    $valid_vars = array_merge( $valid_vars, array( 'meta_key', 'meta_value' ) );
    return $valid_vars;
}
add_filter( 'rest_query_vars', 'my_allow_meta_query' );
```

Calling like so:
`wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[meta_key]=MY-KEY&filter[meta_value]=MY-VALUE`

---

The filter is applied as part of [`WP_REST_Posts_Controller::prepare_items_query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_posts_controller/prepare_items_query/), shown in context here in case that helps:

```
protected function prepare_items_query( $prepared_args = array(), $request = null ) {
    $query_args = array();

    foreach ( $prepared_args as $key => $value ) {
        /**
         * Filters the query_vars used in get_items() for the constructed query.
         *
         * The dynamic portion of the hook name, `$key`, refers to the query_var key.
         *
         * @since 4.7.0
         *
         * @param string $value The query_var value.
         */
        $query_args[ $key ] = apply_filters( "rest_query_var-{$key}", $value );
    }

    if ( 'post' !== $this->post_type || ! isset( $query_args['ignore_sticky_posts'] ) ) {
        $query_args['ignore_sticky_posts'] = true;
    }

    // Map to proper WP_Query orderby param.
    if ( isset( $query_args['orderby'] ) && isset( $request['orderby'] ) ) {
        $orderby_mappings = array(
            'id'      => 'ID',
            'include' => 'post__in',
            'slug'    => 'post_name',
        );

        if ( isset( $orderby_mappings[ $request['orderby'] ] ) ) {
            $query_args['orderby'] = $orderby_mappings[ $request['orderby'] ];
        }
    }

    return $query_args;
}
```